# Generating UML diagram from C# code

Tags: c#, uml, visual-studio-2015

Is there a tool or something that generates UML diagrams from C# code? I'm using Visual Studio 2015(Community) and I know that there is a 'View Class Diagram' option but it doesn't show the relationship between classes.

Comment: Isn't that like generating C# from assembly language?

Comment: @JimL. It's probably more of a re-engineering. Many UML tools offer that. Having said this, I vote to close this as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could with previous version of Visual Studio. In Visual Studio 2015 this features has been removed and no more available even in the Enterprise Edition. You still can generate code from diagram but not the opposite. You will not find much for free (you can try **NCLASS**) if you want to invest money and you have the budget to do there are many good reverse engineering tools: Visual Paradigm Altova...but probably if your only looking for a tool for generating a class diagram from code they offer you much more than you really need.